# Не получается решить проблему с ошибкой ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, python-3.x, калькулятор

Мне нужно сделать калькулятор времени которая при вводе времени, оно пересчитывает на минуту вперёд. Пример:
Вводим 17:30; получаем 17:31
Вводим 23:59; получаем 00:00
Я указал в input 2 переменные (делаю это через сплит). Они стоят в `int`. Когда я компилирую, этот кусок ругается `hour, minute = int(input("напишите время ")).split()` с ошибкой `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`
Я пытлася изменить `int` на `str`, но за ней шла другая ошибка.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: может `.split(':')`?

Comment: `hour, minute = map(int, input("напишите время ЧЧ:ММ ").split(':'))`

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print(
    (datetime.strptime(
        input('Введите время: '),
        '%H:%M') + timedelta(minutes=1)
     ).strftime('%H:%M')
)

# Введите время: 23:59
# 00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
hour, minute = map(int, input("напишите время ЧЧ:ММ ").split(':'))
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours = hour, minutes = minute)
deltaq = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 1)
future = delta + deltaq
print(future)
```

Сначала подключаем модуль datetime.
Водим переменные hour и minute.
В переменной deltaq вводим нудное число минут, которое надо прибавить (также можно прибавить часы) Пример:`datetime.timedelta(minutes = 1,hours= Число часов)`

В результате получаем Часы:Минуты:Секунды

Более подробно описано тут (не реклама): https://tokmakov.msk.ru/blog/item/88

Comment: А чтобы вывести только часы и минуты надо немного попотеть :) `print(f"{int(deltaq.seconds / 3600)}:{(deltaq.seconds // 60) % 60}") `